# Calling UICollectionView#reloadData in UICollectionViewDelegate#collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: hides all cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a UIViewController which has the following implementation for the didSelectItemAtIndexPath

```
@interface

id section1Item
NSMutableArray *section2Items
NSMutableArray *section3Items

@end

@implementation

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        ;

    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

        self.section1Item = [self.section2Items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else { // indexPath.section == 2

        id newSection2Item = [self.section3Items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.section2Items addObject:newSection2Item];

        [self.section3Items removeObject:newSection2Item];

     }


     [collectionView reloadData];

 }

 @end
```

The idea behind the code is that my collectionView has a static number of sections, and taping on an item in section 3 moves the item to section 2, and tapping on an item in section 2 makes it an item in section 1.

However once I make the changes to my dataStructure (section1Item, section2Items and section3Items), and call reloadData, all my UICollectionView cells disappear. A few symptoms of the issue

1. After the reloadData call, non of my dataSource methods get recalled. I tried putting a breakpoint in my implementation of numberOfSectionsInCollectionView and collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection but they don't get hit.
2. I tried debugging using RevealApp, and I found out that after reloadData call, all my UICollectionViewCell's have their hidden property set to "YES", even though I don't have any code in my code base calling .hidden = YES;
3. I also tried overriding UICollectionViewCell#setHidden to detect what (if any) part of the UIKit framework calls it, and again there was no breakpoint triggers.

Tools details: I'm working with XCode5-DP6 on iOS7 simulator.

**UPDATE:** My UICollectionView shows all the cells correctly on first render.

Comment: i supect if your datasource methods is not being called at all means your collectionview itself is nil somehow.

Comment: @BKC I updated my question, but the collectionView is non-nil because my initial render happens correctly.

Comment: There is a solution posted in another thread which worked for me -
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14804429

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok peeps, so I was able to figure out the issue. The delegate (self) was a subclass of `UIViewController`. In the init, I was assigning `self.view = viewFromStoryBoard` where viewFromStoryBoard was passed in by the caller and which was setup in a storyboard.

Since I was not really using any of the facilities offered by subclass `UIViewController`, I decided to switch to subclassing `NSObject` and manually retaining the pointer to the `UICollectionView`.

This fixed my problem. However I'm not a 100% on the exact nature of the issue. I'm guessing  somehow overriding a UIViewController's view isn't all that it seems.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of bugs with iOS 7 and UICollectionView... In my case reloadData doesn't work correctly, it works with delay.

Comment: you will have to give a few more details on "doesn't work correctly", so others can help you. Did you try putting a breakpoint in the delegate methods and see if they get hit after the reloadData call?

Comment: This is not really an answer. You should have written this as a comment.