# Why is this UIAlertView not displaying immediately?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have many UIAlertViews similar to this one that work perfectly.
This one will not display immediately which causes untold grief in my app.

myFantasticViewController.h

```
@interface myFantasticViewController:UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>

-(void)handleUserDefinedStationWarning:(NSError *)error;
```

myFantasticViewController.m

```
-(void)handleUserDefinedStationWarning:(NSError *)error
{
NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"",
                                                                              @"Title for alert displayed when the user-defined station both lat/lon are zero.")
                                                    message:errorMessage
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
[alertView show];
}
```

This is the code which triggers the alertview:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Touch OK to continue without specifying the latitude and longitude."];
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSLocalizedString(message, @"Message displayed when a user-defined station lat/lon are both zero.")
                                                             forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"myFantasticViewController" code:0000 userInfo:userInfo];
[self handleUserDefinedStationWarning:error];
```

... some code ... these statements are executed immediately; the alertview pops up after the code is run which is causing the mayhem.

Comment: Please fix your code formatting!

Comment: "the alertview pops up after the code is run which is causing the mayhem": could you add some more detail? which code is run? could you provide the full implementation for the method calling `handleUserDefinedStationWarning`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UICollectionView doesn't update immediately when calling reloadData, but randomly after 30-60 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804359/uicollectionview-doesnt-update-immediately-when-calling-reloaddata-but-randoml)

Comment: You're probably not calling `handleUserDefinedStationWarning` from the main queue. Try dispatching it to the main queue: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{ [self handleUserDefinedStationWarning:error]; });`

Comment: Make sure that `[self handleUserDefinedStationWarning:error]` is being called on the main queue

Comment: dandan78 - what's wrong with my code formatting?

Comment: Rob - all code is being run on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The reason I was encountering all this grief was because the CPU was doing exactly what I told it to do.
I moved the code that was executing before the alertView displayed to within the clickedButtonAtIndex method.
I was not giving the OS time to display the alertView and was proceeding to do the intended code before the alertView had displayed.